# Why can Excel 2007 not calculate sub formulas right?

Tags: microsoft-excel, windows-10, microsoft-excel-2007

I have the simplest possible scenario:

- open a new Excel 2007 document
- In the first row put 6.99
- In the second row put 4.99
- In the third row put `=A1*0.4`
- And in the fourth row `=SUM((A2-A3)/A2)`

This will print out `0.439679359` but every calculator, plus taking out the sub formula will return `0.438877756` which is correct.

Why is Excel incorrect when using a sub formula?

Comment: Excel is actually correct Excel is performing a rounding operation.  When I calculated 2.194/4.99 I got `0.43967935871743486973947895791583` on the Windows calculator.  Its not clear why you are performing a SUM function though.  "plus taking out the sub formula" - does not make sense to me.

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to have a SUM() in the formula.  I also don't understand what you mean by sub formula

Comment: By sub formula I mean one of the fields being a formula itself

Comment: Ok well I think I solved this anyway and it is something I omitted. I formatted the fields to two decimal places too make 4.99-2.8/4.99 which results in 0.4388 whereas 4.99-2.79/4.99 is 0.4396 so I think this is a issue with Excel still using the real number even when it is formatted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formatting applies only to the *Display*, it does not change the value, and any formula always uses the full value.